# Selenium / Watir TCP connection fails only on worker dyno heroku

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, watir

Why would watir only fail on a heroku worker node?

I'm trying to go to run a basic function of going to google.com. This works fine when I run it on a web dyno but fails when I use delayed job to run it on a worker.

The code is as follows

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "/app/vendor/bundle/bin/chromedriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "google.com"
```

I then receive the following error:

```
Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)
```

I'm using the heroku google chrome, and chromedriver buildpacks and my gemfile is

```
gem 'watir'
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

I've used `heroku ps:exec --dyno=worker.1` and run `rails c` and am able to run the same exact code and not receive the error which makes me belive that it's not an installation error. Why would this fail *only* on a worker node? And I'm also confused why it would work on a worker node with `rails c`.

Comment: Please share if you have solved this error.

Comment: @ray i never figured it out. waitr / selenium was too buggy so i gave up